# Dependence of symbol in regular expressions

Tags: regex

I need to parse a line, that can look as one of these:

```
define a as 5
define b as 5.5
define c as "hello, stackoverflow"
```

I'm trying to do this with regular expressions.
For this I wrote pattern 
`'define ([a-zA-Z_]\w*) as ([\w"][\w \.]*[\w"]*)'`

 My problem that I don't understand is there any way to check: if smth after word `as` starts with `"` then it should end with `"`. Thanks for any comments and suggestions.

Comment: Maybe [`define ([a-zA-Z_]\w*) as ("[^"]+"|[\w.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/pN1jE8/1) is enough?

Comment: Which programming language are you using ?Which programming language are you using ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. That's it. My bad ;)

Comment: @PedroLobito I'm using python3.

Comment: Program language parsing? `"[^"]+"` is not the way to parse strings. Though `".*?"` is faster.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know you can't have quotes in quoted strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using alternation:

```
define ([a-zA-Z_]\w*) as ("[^"]+"|[\w.]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pN1jE8/1)

The `("[^"]+"|[\w.]+)` captures either a quoted substring that has no quotes inside (`"[^"]+"` - to allow empty `""`, use `*` instead of `+`) -OR- 1+ word characters or dots (matched with `[\w.]+`).